# A view with research limited to a category (taxonomy)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I've a taxonomy which forms categories and subcategories. For each node, one of these category terms (vocabulary: categories) should be choosen, as well as other terms like "intelligent", "stupid", "bad" (vocabulary : definition).

- Animals
  1. Dog
  2. Cat
  3. Bird
- Human
  1. Girls
  2. Boys
  3. Robot
- Insects
  1. Arachnida
  2. Crustacea
  3. Trilobites

I would ike to create a view, with research field (filter by vocabulary: definition) for each category.

In other terms :

- a view for "animals" where the user launch a research for  "intelligent", "stupid", "bad"
- a view for "human" where the user launch a research for  "intelligent", "stupid", "bad"
- a view for "Insects" where the user launch a research for  "intelligent", "stupid", "bad"

I cannot find the good configuration which allows to limit the research to a certain part of the vocabulary. Any idea? Thanks !